# Can we change the header of the Custom object Detail page?

Tags: administration, salesforce-classic

I have a custom object and the detail page of the object has an Text ID, a standard field as header. Can we change it to the name which is the custom field. Attached is a snip where i wanted to change the header.[image]

In the above picture i would like to change the Header "Test-W-1111" and my own custom field value to it.

Comment: can not be done on page layouts. although I feel it would be a great feature...however if its really a business-critical thing, you could go for custom VF page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce by default shows the Name field for a custom object as header where Name is applicable.

Though, through Feed based page layout you can display custom fields at Highlight Panel in console.

[image: Highlight Panel]

Sample Case record

[image: Sample Case record]

Highlight Panel in Case - console

[image: Highlight Panel in Case - console]

For classic view, the custom fields cannot be shown until we build a Visualforce page using `<apex:sectionHeader/>`